# Cómo actualizar el valor de una columna específica en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

la pregunta es como puedo actualizar el valor de una columna específica en SQL sin tener que enviar datos de los otros campos, me explico con el código.

tengo el siguiente Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateCredito]
 @CreditoID int,
 @PersonaID int,
 @NumeroCuotas int,
 @EstadoCredito int,
 @MontoAprovado decimal (18,2),
 @Plazo int,
 @FechaCredito datetime,
 @Tasa decimal (4,2)
AS
 BEGIN
  UPDATE Credito SET
      PersonaID = @PersonaID,
      NumeroCuotas = @NumeroCuotas,
      EstadoCredito = @EstadoCredito,
      MontoAprovado = @MontoAprovado,
      Plazo = @Plazo,
      FechaCredito = @FechaCredito,
     Tasa = @Tasa
  WHERE
   CreditoID = @CreditoID
  END
```

en una rutina se necesita cambiar SOLO EstadoCredito pero no quiero actualizar las demas columnas.

si lo ejecuto desde sql manager seria asi:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spUpdateCredito]
    @CreditoID = 3,
    @PersonaID = NULL,
    @NumeroCuotas = NULL,
    @EstadoCredito = 5,
    @MontoAprovado = NULL,
    @Plazo = NULL,
    @FechaCredito = NULL,
    @Tasa = NULL

 SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

pero no quiero que me deje columnas en null

si solo quiero que me actualice la columna especifica, ejecuto el script

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spUpdateCredito]
    @CreditoID = 3,
    @EstadoCredito = 5


SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Sale el siguiente error

**Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure spUpdateCredito, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
El procedimiento o la función 'spUpdateCredito' esperaba el parámetro '@PersonaID', que no se ha especificado.**

Solicitando los otros columnas, como seria para que se actualice la columna especifica

**UPDATE** NO ES CREAR Otra rutina o script es utilizar esta misma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar el error lo obtienes por que los parámetros del Sp esperan que les pases un valor, para que no sea necesario hacerlo hay que definirle un valor default a cada uno, por ejemplo:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateCredito]
          @CreditoID int,  -- Este debiera ser el único obligatorio
          @PersonaID int = NULL,
...
```

Y así con cada parámetro. Ahora el problema lo tienes en que al no definir un parámetro el valor del mismo será `NULL` lo cual es algo que no queremos ya que lo estamos usando en un `UPDATE`, una posibilidad es preguntar mediante un `IF` si el valor NO es `NULL` y entonces disparar el `UPDATE`solo para ese campo:

```
IF @PersonaID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  UPDATE Credito SET
         PersonaID = @PersonaID
         WHERE CreditoID = @CreditoID
END
```

El problema que tiene esto es que seguramente estamos ejecutando múltiples `UPDATE` uno por cada campo. La alternativa a esto es usar una sola sentencia de `UPDATE` pero con `ISNULL` en cada parámetro, en caso que el mismo sea `NULL` actualizaremos con el mismo valor:

```
  UPDATE Credito SET
         PersonaID = ISNULL(@PersonaID, PersonaID),
         ...
         WHERE CreditoID = @CreditoID
```

Con estos dos consejos tu SP podría quedar así:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateCredito]
 @CreditoID int, -- Este debiera ser el único obligatorio
 @PersonaID int = NULL,
 @NumeroCuotas int = NULL,
 @EstadoCredito int = NULL,
 @MontoAprovado decimal (18,2) = NULL,
 @Plazo int = NULL,
 @FechaCredito datetime = NULL,
 @Tasa decimal (4,2) = NULL
AS
 BEGIN
  UPDATE Credito SET
      PersonaID = ISNULL(@PersonaID,PersonaID),
      NumeroCuotas = ISNULL(@NumeroCuotas,NumeroCuotas)
      EstadoCredito = ISNULL(@EstadoCredito,EstadoCredito)
      MontoAprovado = ISNULL(@MontoAprovado,MontoAprovado)
      Plazo = ISNULL(@Plazo,Plazo)
      FechaCredito = ISNULL(@FechaCredito,FechaCredito)
      Tasa = ISNULL(@Tasa, Tasa)
  WHERE
   CreditoID = @CreditoID
  END
```

Un comentario más, si quisiéramos ser super exquisitos, hay ciertas situaciones que eventualmente quisiéramos evitar:

1. Que todos los parámetros sean `NULL`
2. Que los valores de los parámetros sean idénticos a los de la tabla

Claramente en estos dos casos no habría sentido hacer el `UPDATE`, una forma sencilla de controlarlo es en la misma sentencia de `UPDATE`, agregando más condiciones al `WHERE`:

```
WHERE
   CreditoID = @CreditoID
   AND ( 
          ( (PersonaId IS NULL AND @PersonaID IS NOT NULL) OR PersonaID <> ISNULL(@PersonaID, PersonaID))
          OR ( (NumeroCuotas IS NULL AND @NumeroCuotas IS NOT NULL) OR NumeroCuotas <> ISNULL(@NumeroCuotas, NumeroCuotas))
          ...
       )
```

Y por último es importante aclarar que esta forma de actualizar los datos no permitiría eventualmente modificar una columna para que la misma sea `NULL`, es decir por ejemplo "nullear" `FechaCredito`, esto se puede resolver pero habría que modificar un poco la lógica, usando algún "Flag" que "fuerze" el `NULL` en estos caso.

Comment: Excelete you r the guy!!! lo que estaba buscando!! Patricio Gracias

Comment: @ger me alegro que te sirva, agregué unos comentarios más, saludos

Answer (score 1):

La rutina almacenada está hecha para actualizar todos los campos, 
por tal seria mejor crear una rutina nueva para actualizar solo esos datos y pasar menos parametros o condicionar dentro del procedimiento en base a los valores nulos. por ejemplo

```
if isnull(@parametroX) and isnull(parametroY) then
//consulta de actualizacion de cierta cantidad de campos
else
//consulta de actualizacion de todos los campos
end if;
```

Comment: Si la idea es no crear otra rutina, pero veo que tu código se acerca a lo que busco